# Can I suppress particular tiny mce buttons for one field of a content type (dexterity)?

Tags: plone, dexterity

Can I suppress particular tiny mce buttons for one field of a content type (dexterity model)?
That is, I'd like people to be able to format text but not insert images.

Answer (score 2):

for archetypes you can use this snippet.
you can use either `allow_buttons` or `filter_buttons`.
([see the documentation for more details](http://plone.org/products/tinymce/documentation/how-to/how-to-customize-tinymce-for-an-archetypes-richwidget))

let me know if the [WysiwygFieldWidget](http://developer.plone.org/reference_manuals/external/plone.app.dexterity/advanced/rich-text-markup-transformations.html) uses the same options:

```
atapi.TextField('text',
    storage=atapi.AnnotationStorage(),
    schemata=u'details',
    required=False,
    searchable=True,
    validators=(('isTidyHtmlWithCleanup', V_REQUIRED),
          ),
    default_output_type='text/x-html-safe',
    widget=atapi.RichWidget(
        label=_(u"Descriptive Text"),
        description=_(u"Text describing the object in detail"),
        redefine_parastyles=True,
        parastyles=(
            'Heading 1|h2',
            'Heading 2|h3'),
        allow_buttons=('pasteword', 'style', 'bold', 'italic', 'bullist',),
        #filter_buttons = ('save-button', 'bg-justify', 'definitionlist',
        #                  'tabledrawer-button', 'bg-remove', 'olstyles', 'zoom'),
        rows=20, #xxx no effect: https://dev.plone.org/ticket/13113
        allow_file_upload=False,
        ),
    ),
```